# Put shadow to a rectangle (drawRect:(CGRect)rect)

Tags: objective-c, drawrect, cgrectmake

I did a rectangle with this code and it works:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(60, 60, 100, 1));
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

But now i want to put a shadow, I tried with this:

```
NSShadow* theShadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
[theShadow setShadowOffset:NSMakeSize(10.0, -10.0)];
[theShadow setShadowBlurRadius:4.0];
```

But xcode tell me about  `NSMakeSize : Sending 'int' to parameter of incompatible type 'CGSize'`

Which is the correct form about shadows?
Thanks!!

Comment: Try `CGSizeMake` instead of `NSMakeSize`?

Comment: I changed that you comment me and now xcode don't tell me error, but doesn't appear the shadow

Comment: What about using `CGContextSetShadow()`?

Comment: actually I'm trying too with that :
CGColorRef shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(1, -1), 2, shadowColor);

Comment: But,,, happens nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should invoke `CGContextSetShadow(...)` function before the functions that draw object that should have a shadow. Here is the complete code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // define constants
    const CGFloat shadowBlur = 5.0f;
    const CGSize shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1, 0, 0, 1);

    // Setup shadow parameters. Everithyng you draw after this line will be with shadow
    // To turn shadow off invoke CGContextSetShadowWithColor(...) with NULL for CGColorRef parameter.
    CGContextSetShadow(context, shadowOffset, shadowBlur);

    CGRect rectForShadow = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width - shadowOffset.width - shadowBlur, rect.size.height - shadowOffset.height - shadowBlur);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rectForShadow);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

**Remarks:**

I have noticed that you provide some random values to `CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(60, 60, 100, 1));`. You should draw only within the rectangle that you receive through `rect` parameter.

Comment: ooooo yeah!!! Now I can see the shadows, thanks so much.. ok,, You have reason in your remarks , so it depends of the rectangle?

Comment: @user2958588, as per apple documentation: `You should limit any drawing to the rectangle specified in the rect parameter.`
The reason for this as I think is to improve rendering performance. 
Note that rectangle size and origin can differ from you view's frame because some parts of the view can be already rendered thus iOS may request only a part to be rerendered again.