# Convert float value to double in objective c

Tags: objective-c, casting, drawrect, cgrectmake

I have use the cast to convert a string to int,  a string to double  and it works.

Now I want to convert a float value to double and xcode tell me:

> "Pointer cannot be cast to type 'double'",

My float variable is declared in .h

```
@property float *valueX, *valueY
```

And in .m I do:

```
double dou = (double) valorX;
```

What happen here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what you're asking here but I imagine the problem is the * in the float properties.

A float property should be declared as...

```
@property float valueX;
```

not

```
@property float *valueX;
```

(unless it's a pointer to a float but I doubt that's the case here)

**Note**

You probably should be doing something like this...

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat valueX;
```

Comment: YEA,, my problem was the * .. but thanks for response :D

Comment: @user2958588 yes, that's what my answer is. I specifically showed that you should not use the *. The other answer is incorrect. Just saying. So far, the only correct answer on this question is mine.

Comment: actually, i just put attention when I read : * ... and I said me: ¿Whatt.?. I forgot to quit the * -_- ,, hey but you can helping with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636304/put-shadow-to-a-rectangle-drawrectcgrectrect?noredirect=1#comment38185554_24636304

Answer (score 1):

You declare valueX as a `float *`, meaning a pointer to a float.

You need to first dereference the pointer to get the floating point value it contains, then cast the result to a double

```
double dou = (double)(*valueX);
```

You could also think of this as a two-step process

```
float tempFloat = *valueX;
double dou = (double) tempFloat;
```

If you did not mean to declare valueX as a `float *`, change the declaration to `float`.

Comment: I think that in this case, the * was a mistake in the first place. Based on the poster's description, it seems like she wants a simple primitive.

Comment: -_- I hadn't saw that ...  *

Comment: @user2958588 I'd take a look at which answer is actually correct before accepting them though :-)